# Ella habría ido si ella hubiera sabido que él está allá (¿o estaba allá?) ¿Cuáles son las reglas de concordancia en este caso?

Tags: subjuntivo

> Ella habría ido si ella hubiera sabido que él está allá

¿O estaba allá?) ¿Cuáles son las reglas de concordancia en este caso?

Estoy familiarizada con las reglas de concordancia en la primera oración y en el verbo que sigue a la oración de "si", pero no estoy segura de las reglas de concordancia con el verbo que sigue.

Comment: En francês, português y español, cuando hay el mismo sujeto en las dos oraciones (una principal y otra subordinada), no se usa el subjuntivo. Es lo que dije en mi respuesta, y la mantengo. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con oraciones condicionales hipotéticas pasadas, como es el caso en cuestión, si hay otras subordinadas pueden ir en presente o pasado dependiendo de si la situación descripta por la subordinada sigue siendo o no válida en el presente.

En la oración:

(1) Ella habría ido si ella hubiera sabido que él está allá (él **está** actualmente allá, pero ella no lo sabe: si hubiera sabido, habría ido).

En cambio, en la oración:

(2) Ella habría ido si ella hubiera sabido que él estaba allá (cabe la posibilidad de que él **ya no esté** allá).

No obstante, la oración (1) puede ser objetada por algunos gramáticos que sostienen que debe mantenerse la perspectiva pasada en toda la oración, independientemente de que, en este caso, él todavía esté allá o no.

Agrego un par de ejemplos de Internet:

> Si no se hubiera realizado la prueba, probablemente no se habría sabido que **tiene** Covid, debido a que muchos no presentaban síntomas. [Fuente](https://rotativo.com.mx/2021/02/16/noticias/locales/san-juan-del-rio/exitoso-programa-de-pruebas-covid-19-en-san-juan-del-rio-885696/)

La situación es que la persona tiene actualmente Covid.

> Si no se hubiera hecho la prueba, no habría sabido que **tenía** el virus. [Fuente](https://luchanoticias.com/aj-styles-revela-cuando-descubrio-que-tenia-covid-19/)

No se sabe si la persona tiene todavía el virus o no.

---

Nota: Creo necesario aclarar que la cita mencionada en la otra respuesta:

> [...] se emplea el Subjuntivo cuando los sujetos de ambas oraciones son distintos, mientras que cuando la oración principal y la subordinada (dictum) tienen el mismo sujeto, ésta se construye en infinitivo. Se trata de un mecanismo generalizado en muchas otras lenguas pero que no afecta al contenido semántico ni a la intención comunicativa del mensaje, es decir, a la modalidad. En algunos casos sin embargo, se aprecian diferencias significativas, bajo construcciones aparentemente semejantes, como ocurre con las llamadas construcciones perifrásticas.

no aplica en absoluto al caso en cuestión. No hay *modus* y *dictum* en la oración condicional que se está tratando. El caso al que se refiere el párrafo es éste:

- No quiero que yo vaya. (NO GRAMATICAL)

En este caso, como coincide el sujeto del *modus* y del *dictum*, debe usarse infinitivo:

- No quiero ir.

En cambio, se puede usar subjuntivo cuando los sujetos difieren:

- No quiero que ella vaya. (GRAMATICAL)

Con verbos cognitivos, a veces se usa subjuntivo y otras, infinitivo:

- No creo que (yo) vaya.
- No pienso ir.

Answer (score -3):

> [...] se emplea el Subjuntivo cuando los sujetos de ambas oraciones
> son distintos, mientras que c**uando la oración principal y la
> subordinada (dictum) tienen el mismo sujeto, ésta se construye en
> infinitivo**. Se trata de un mecanismo generalizado en muchas otras
> lenguas pero que no afecta al contenido semántico ni a la intención
> comunicativa del mensaje, es decir, a la modalidad. En algunos casos
> sin embargo, se aprecian diferencias significativas, bajo
> construcciones aparentemente semejantes, como ocurre con las llamadas
> construcciones perifrásticas.

[verbos modales y modalidad](https://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/9789/1/ELUA_Anexo2_20.pdf)

"habría ido si ella hubiera sabido que él está allá" se ajusta en, a  mi ver:

"Ella habría ido al saber que (él o ella) estaba allá".

o, por ejemplo:

"Ella habría ido si sabia que (él o ella) estaba allá".

- No creo que vaya a la playa. (él o ella vaya, sujetos diferentes del yo no creo)
- No creo que voy a playa. (mismo sujeto, se usa el presente)

Que sepa yo, no se usa el subjuntivo en la segunda oración (subordinada) si tiene el mismo sujeto que la primera (principal).

Comment: "Si ella lo hubiera sabido, ella habría ido" es una oración condicional estándar, equivalente al *third conditional* en inglés. Véase [el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/si#112b) en el punto 1.1.2 b), donde hay ejemplos como "*Si hubieras/hubieses estudiado, habrías aprobado*". La "regla" citada en esta respuesta solo es válida en algunos casos, y las oraciones condicionales son definitivamente una excepción.

Comment: @wimi La frase dada fue:"**Ella habría** ido si **ella hubiera sabido** que él está alla". No está bien. No lleva subjuntivo.

Comment: La oración "Ella habría ido si hubiera sabido" (se recomienda dejar el segundo "ella" tácito) está en perfecto español. Decir lo contrario es un claro error.

Comment: @mimi el punto 1.1.2 b) dice: También en este caso debe evitarse el empleo en la prótasis del condicional compuesto o antepospretérito, que se da, como ya se ha indicado antes (→ a), entre hablantes de algunas zonas de América y del norte de España: **Si lo habría sabido, te lo hubiera dicho**. Claro, que se puede usar *Si hubieras/hubiese estudiado*, el problema no está en eso. Es tener dos sujetos iguales en dos oraciones en donde el segundo está en el subjuntivo. ¡ Como dice el punto que citas !

Comment: @Lambie no, el punto dice que se debe evitar usar el **condicional** en la **prótasis** (la parte con *si*). Es decir, que *si lo habría sabido, te lo hubiera dicho* es incorrecto, pero *si lo hubiera sabido, te lo habría dicho* es correcto. El ejemplo del punto 1.1.2b "Si hubieras/hubieses estudiado, habrías aprobado" tiene el mismo sujeto en las dos oraciones, y usa subjuntivo. ¿Cómo lo dirías si no?

Comment: @Lambie el orden de las oraciones no importa. Lo que importa es cuál es la prótasis y cual es la apódosis. Decir "Habrías aprobado si hubieras estudiado" es igual de correcto que decir "Si hubieras estudiado, habrías aprobado".